# Custom GUI without desktop environment

Tags: command-line, window-manager, gui

I want to set up a custom Linux OS primarily for hobby and learning use. It doesn't need a desktop environment, but I do want to at least customize the visual appearance of the window manager and maybe a taskbar. Applications (with GUI) can be run using the terminal, which would be the default application after booting. Basically, I want it to have the look-and-feel of an old computer, but relying on my own graphics for the GUI. It also needs to be able to be controlled entirely using the keyboard.

I have knowledge of Linux and understand what a window manager, desktop environment, etc. are, but I don't have direct knowledge of developing for Linux. I have searched around the web for tools and techniques to make such a GUI, but there is so much info that I'm getting a bit confused about what I could use and do. I can get a bare Linux distro without a GUI, and I know I have to install at least a window manager for a GUI to appear, but that's the point, I want to have a custom GUI with taskbar, but I'm looking at this more from a graphic designer's point of view than a programmer's, so I don't really know where to continue from there. I was thinking of using Qt or SDL for the GUI and the applications. So my question is really about how to create a custom GUI without developing a window manager from scratch. Python/Lua or even C# are preferred, but C++ is not a problem.

FYI, it is not meant to work as a standard OS like Ubuntu. It's for specific use and only intended to run my own simple applications (I run the OS as a virtual machine). The system is for a very specific and unique purpose, but I'm unsure how people will react if they knew what is was for. This is not something for professional use, nor really serious, but just some exploration into understanding Linux, and operating systems in general.

Comment: So are you looking to write your own window manager, or write your own X server? Are you sure you understand the architecture? You do not need a window manager to have a GUI (only to have a comfortable GUI).

Comment: No, I don't really want to write my own X server or even a window manager. I'm not that experienced. I really just want to customize the actual appearance of the GUI. Basically, the system needs to represent an embedded or kiosk system, just with more than one application + terminal

Comment: So you want a WM with a minimalist look? Have you browsed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Window_manager and https://duckduckgo.com/?q=minimalist+window+manager ?

Comment: I wonder, since I just want a few simple applications, can I just use Qt, for example, to create an application that simulates the main GUI I want (launched through the Linux terminal), such as the taskbar, then launching other Qt-based applications through that? It doesn't need to be complex or anything. This already makes it much like a kiosk system. It appears that as long as the Qt libraries are installed, I can run a (full-screen) Qt-based application without any window manager or desktop environment.

Comment: You need an X server to have a GUI. Beyond that, you don't need a window manager if you're running a single application. With multiple applications, technically, you don't need a window manager, but in practice, you do want one, otherwise switching between windows is painful. Additional features such as a task bar are beyond the scope of window managers and into desktop environments though some WM do offer a task bar.

Comment: Is it possible to then have a completely empty desktop environment with only my custom taskbar? Qt can use borderless windows, so a simple (tiling) window manager to render the applications always full screen and only switch with the keyboard is enough, also with shortcuts to launch applications and switch to them. Then the X server is just configured to launch the default application. Also, since KDE uses Qt, can I create my custom taskbar/desktop with Qt, then have KDE use it, or is that going too far?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26192/discussion-between-n-van-oosten-and-gilles).

Answer (score 2):

The role of an [X11 window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager) is quite complex. First, learn more about [X core protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol) and [X architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture). Then read [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) if you need to understand the *conventional* roles of WMs (also known and respected by X11 [toolkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) like [GTK](http://gtk.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/), etc...).

<sup>Even single-application but multiple-windows (e.g. popups) programs practically need some WM</sup>

Then you could choose, or configure, or perhaps patch, some [window manager](http://xwinman.org/) to suite your particular needs. Perhaps [awesome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_%28window_manager%29), since it is scriptable in Lua, might please you (and you could find other scriptable window managers, or patch some existing one...). Some window managers are using only or mostly the keyboard (e.g. [ratpoison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/), [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/), etc...)

<sup>(writing your own EWMH-compliant window manager would take you too much time)</sup>